# Updating existing record in parse.com not working it doing duplication

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com demo, I want to update an existing entry from a table in parse.com. Each time it makes a duplicate entry. I have tried what's below.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MQOD");

        // query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.whereEqualTo("DeviceId", android_id);

        // query.toString();
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::QUERY:::::::::::::::"
                + query);
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        testObject.put("DeviceId", android_id);
        testObject.put("InstallationDate", subscriptionDate);
        testObject.put("Subscription", "Done");
        testObject.put("NextSubscription", upGradeDate);

        try {
            testObject.save();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // Purchase error...!!
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::Purchase consumehas failed:::::::::::::::::::::");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code seems that you don't use the standard field id `objectID`( that is the official id field used in all the Parse class table ) but the `DeviceId` ( i suppose it is your custom field ) .

Otherwise you have to make your `DeviceId` as unique field, and to make it possible, you have to check the new incoming DeviceId in the "beforeSave" parse trigger, and so check if the element already exist or not ( see also this: https://www.parse.com/questions/unique-fields--2 )

So, at now it's normal that you obtain a dubplicate each time, because it is considered as Insert instead of Update ( since you don't specify the `objectId` )

Hope it helps